# C# .Net Core 6 - Segmentation fault (core dumped) on linux fedora

Tags: c#, .net-core, openssl, dotnetcorecli

I have a compiled succesfuly a .Net core dll, on a win10 machine and a fedora 35 both with .Net core 6 sdk, from
https://github.com/MindFlavor/prometheus_sql_server_exporter

On win10, it runs correctly and executes correctly when I visit http://localhost:9966.

When I run on the fedora box, I get correct output as  a start

> Hosting environment: Production Content root path:
> /home/salam/projects/prometheus_sql_server_exporter Now listening on:
> http://[::]:9966 Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

Executing anything like visiting the url http://localhost:9966 as on the win10 machine I get right away

> Segmentation fault (core dumped) .

Not sure where I can find any log or how to debug. On MS site at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-fedora#troubleshoot-the-package-manager
there a hint in the dependencies section indicating

If the target runtime environment's OpenSSL version is 1.1 or newer, you'll need to install compat-openssl10.

> Mine is 1.1.11

I tried to install compat-openssl10 but it is not available starting Fedoar 34 as it seems it has security issues. So is this is really the problem or it is something else?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Yes, I did, then  dotnet new console, then dotnet run. it worked fine

Comment: Not sure we're talking about the same thing. Perhaps you can read the link? Exerpt: "Your code examples should be ... Minimal – Use as little code as possible that **still produces the same problem** ... Complete – Provide all parts someone else needs to **reproduce your problem in the question itself**"

Comment: it is very easy to reproduce, clone the git project, compile and run

Comment: David784, not sure I understnad what do you want me to do, I gave all details and error message is very clear, and MS docs to setup are clear also, what you need more?

Comment: Take the code you are working with. Throw away all the parts that don't figure into this, boiling it down to a [mcve]. Post that code and repro instructions

Comment: I also have same errors. This looks like a hardware issue to me. It's either RAM or the drive.